# Is there a way to permanently save the uuid created in the Android app?

Tags: android

The uuid created as shown below in the Android app is saved as a **file** in the storage.

```
ex)

val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/" + FILE_NAME
val file = File(path)
BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(file.path)).use { stream ->
    stream.write(uuid.toByteArray())
}
```

After updating to Android11 ​​(targetSdkVersion 30), files cannot be saved in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage?hl=ena#scoped-storage

The uuid must remain as credentials to identify the user even if the app is reinstalled.
Is there a new way to save the uuid instead of being unable to save it to a file?

Please let me know if there is a place where I can change the save file path or save it in the system area such as iOS keychain.

Supplement:
Currently, the file in which the uuid is saved is saved in a hidden file (.file) so that it will not be deleted by the user as much as possible.

What I tried:

- I was able to save the file in the Picture, Download directory, After
  reinstalling, I can no longer access the files I created.
- I've tried backup, but it's not good because deleting the storage cache can easily lead to loss of backup data
  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup?hl=en

Comment: Any luck? I'm looking for the same thing, but my app is for wearables